# Storing Large Number of IP Addresses in Memory

Tags: java, data-structures, out-of-memory, sparse-matrix, bitset

Question is a bit long so please bear with me.

I'm writing java code to aggregate flows from a full day network trace into 84 sec bins for each subnet. Currently, I have upto 256 subnets and 1024 bins for each subnet. I use this to acquire traffic feature statistics such as number of connections, in/out bytes, number of external ip addresses in each window of each subnet. While connections, in/out bytes is simple, getting unique number of exteran ip addresses is causing OutOfMemory errors.

To determine unique number of external ip addresses, I need to store IP address in some data structure such as hash table, and at the end of trace I can get the size of this hashtable. This means I'll have 1024*256 hashtables, each storing large number of 12-15 byte IP Address strings (tens to thousands). This quickly blows up and system goes out of memory (I've tried to set java heap size to upto 2GB with no avail). Can anyone suggest a way to store such a large number of objects efficiently?

I tried using bitset (converting ip to a int) however considering ip addresses are very very sparse, it doesn't help with memory situation. As the last resort, I might use colt library sparse matrices with each double storing upto 64 ip addresses but I wanted to get an opinion in case I'm missing something obvious and can save up on time writing/debugging such a wrapper.

Sidenotes: To get an idea of scale, I see several hundred million flows per trace that I parse and aggregate. I'm using 10 to 20 of 256 subnets in most cases but I'd like the solution to be scalable to all 256 subnets.

Comment: First, a few quick back-of-the-envelope calculations:

1024*256*15*10000/(1024^3) = roughly 40 GB, assuming your hashtables only take up one byte (it's more likely a few thousand).  That's a lot, but not too much that an expensive server couldn't handle... ;)

I'm not clear on why you need all of this in RAM, but assuming you can't make do with an on-disk database, it seems like you might be better off distributing the load across multiple machines.

Comment: How many distinct IP addresses do you have? And are they clustered in particular subnets?

Comment: Ben, I'm a grad student and do not have access to a cluster of servers. Also, currently, I'm taking roughly 10-15 minutes per trace. If I use a dist based storage, it'll simply take way too much time, probably in several hours or even a day. I need to keep a count of all unique IP Addresses for each bin in each subnet and that'd require storage to check for uniqueness.

kdgregory, I'm keep a count of all ip address machines in a subnet connect to. The possible range is all of IP-V4 addresses and there is no restriction. You might be accessing google on 8.8.8.8 and something else 202.192.1.1.

Comment: The real question I was asking was about sparseness. If your data is truly sparse (ie, a million addresses, concentrated in a few thousand IP ranges) then you can make use of the fact that Java multi-dimensional arrays are not fully allocated (ie, `int[256][][][]` only occupies the space required for 256 pointers).

Comment: Take a look at SparseBitSet, it should reduce your memory consumption dramatically and you may be able to go back to your original BitSet implementation: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/SparseBitSet

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
If you stored the entire 4 Billion IPv4 addresses as a single array then you could represent time as an individual short.

```
short[] ipv4 = new short[Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2]; // technically not possible blah blah
```

That'd be 8GB with 65K time resolution.  Just consider that because it puts an upper bound on the memory because any other scheme must be under that.  If you used a byte it'd be 256 time resolution for 337.5 sec per bin, and 4 GB.

Now that gives you only a bit to say you saw at least a packet within that bucket.  If you need a count that blows up the memory again, but with a short you could use 1024 buckets with a potential 6 bit resolution for counting: 64 packet max.

Now with 100 million unique IPs that reduces memory by 10x so you went from 8GB to 800MB in theory.  While not allocating the entire space you think you can save memory, but you still have to store 4 bytes per IP: 400MB just for the IPs + 400MB for some sort structure to hold them (100M pointers * 4 bytes), and 2 bytes for time: 1GB minimum.  By allocating the full space you get the ability to skip storing the IP over again because your hash is your IP.  If you reduce the array you don't have the IP anymore because it's been hashed away.  Now you could not store the IP and still answer questions given an IP, but you can't regurgitate it.

What if you stored a series of subnet masks, and then rolled up all the IPs underneath that, and keep your stats on that subnet mask.  For example, you have 256 subnets with their own subnet mask.  Your program would take in a lower bound of the mask.  That being if you mask is 209.134.0.0/16 and use a lower bound of 8.  Then it would create 256 bins for that subnet that were apart of 209.134.0.0-209.134.255.255.  You'd repeat that same process for all 256 subnets you have.  With a lower bound of 8 bits means the lower 256 addresses of each subnet would be rolled up.  You can hash any IP address into the bin and keep statistics in memory.  However, you can't say anything about a single IP address.  But, if you need more resolution you can just drop the lower subnet mask say to 4, and now there are more bins.

You only create a bin if you have 1 IP within it so if you don't have IPs showing up there you can save some space so it's balancing act between low enough for descent resolution, but high enough to skip creating bins for things you don't need.

Then you could write out a log of each bin and track what occurred in each bin on the disk.  If you want to answer a question about a single IP you figure out which bin it belongs in then open the file and search within there to find the answer.  This scheme means you can scale up or down depending on the size of your data, and by raising and lowering your bounds.  You could get performance boost by changing the file structure you write out per bin.

I know sorry for the length! :-)

Comment: Bins are time bins and not IP bins i.e 84*1024 is approx a whole day's data. I do not have a range constraint on IP so I'd need a translation mechanism to find its location in array which, effectively makes it hash map. Also X is very very diverse. For some less active subnet, it can be in 10s, for most it is in 100s so preallocating memory will be problematic. What you suggested, with exception of hash map instead of array, was what I did and it was still using too much memory.

Comment: That really wasn't clear in your question: 1024 vs 84.  But essentially you're adding in another multiplyier 84 to the mix.  Updating my answer.

Comment: 84 doesn't matter. That is just duration of each bin i.e. I aggregate all connections active in 84 sec window into 1 bin for example 10:00:00 to 10:01:24 in bin 1. I wanted to keep things concise so I didn't add all that information, which in hindsight, I should have.

Comment: Crap. Ok I think I finally got this.  When you wrote 1024 * 84 that's confusing too.  I took out the memory analysis.  Didn't reduce it much.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort. I'll try it after @brian-roach effort. Currently, after storing ip as unsigned int (i.e. I don't care if its positive or negative) in a hashset and some optimizations, I'm able to run it though solution definitely isn't scalable. I'll get back to you after trying your solution though I'm still a little skeptical. Still I'm grateful for the effort.

Comment: Take a look at SparseBitSet, it should reduce your memory consumption dramatically and you may be able to go back to your original BitSet implementation: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/SparseBitSet

Answer (score 1):

Not not sure why you have 1024*256?

You only need one data structure  to hold all the data; Use a red-black tree keyed by the IP as a 4-byte integer. This gives you O(log(n)) lookup time which means worst case is 32 comparisons to find an IP. Or a `HashMap` keyed by `Integer`.

In each node have your 84 "bin" objects (stored in a Linked list, Array, or whatever makes sense in terms of the access pattern you have) that contain the information you want to store. If you only need the aggregate ... only store the aggregate. This really would cut down your memory usage.

**Edit:** I tend to forget about Java `int`s being signed. That doesn't pose a problem unless you actually want to sort them easily in which case use a `long`/`Long`

Comment: My internal network is class B, it has a range of 256*256 IP addresses. I'm dividing it into 256 subnets, so each subnet is like 128.0.1.x, 128.0.2.x upto 128.0.255.x. 1024 is the number of time bins for each subnet, and these 1024 bins constitute 24 hours. So a connection from 128.0.1.127 that stays active for the whole day will have its destination in all 1024 bins of that particular subnet.
Subnets are based on internal ip of the network while I want to keep track of all the external IP addr that internal users connect to. Think of it as IPs of all sites people in 128.0.1.x browse to.

Comment: So considering all this, it seemed to me as if you're aggregating on external ip addresses when external IP addresses themselves are part of aggregation for the subnet. Basically, I want to know number of unique external IPs for each subnet/bin so I can identify if, for example, there's suddenly a huge spike. Please correct me if I misunderstood your solution. I should've explained all the above in my first post but I wanted to keep it relatively concise.

Answer (score 0):

I would have multiple BitSets e.g.

```
private final BitSet[] ips = new BitSet[256*256*256];

public void sample(int address) {
   BitSet bs = ips[address >>> 8];
   if (bs == null)
      ips[address >>> 8] = new BitSet();
   bs.set(address & 0xFFFF);
}

public int count() {
   int total = 0;
   for(BitSet bs: ips)
      total += bs.cardinality();
   return total;
}
```

This will as little as 1 bit per address, depending on how spare the IP address.  Given many address ranges won't appear, memory consumption could be very efficient.  Its very hard to test without a realistic dataset. ;)

The worst case memory size is 512 MB, but it should be much less than this for realistic data sets.

Comment: That is very interesting yet simple. At the very least it'll eliminate consumption for subnets with very few IPs. I'll report back with test results on my dataset.

Comment: Just tried this approach and still get OutOfMemory error. While first ips array locations are allocated on need based, the bs BitSet will still get a diverse set of IPs and will need on average 4096 bytes. So even for 15 different IPs in upper half, and just 20 out 256 subnets is consumes 1024*20*15*409 = 1,258,291,200 bytes or 1.2 GB memory, and this is average or even better than average case. Anyway interesting approach nonetheless.

Comment: I have adjusted the distribution, can you try it now?